# Evaluating the triple integral $\iiint \limits_R ze^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \, \, dV$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the following triple integrals as a repeated integral using an appropriate coordinate systems: $$\iiint\limits_R ze^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \, \, dV ,$$ where $$R=\{ (x,y,z): \, x,y \in (-\infty, \infty), \, 0 \leq z \leq 1 \}.$$

It is simple to integrate after using cylindrical coordinates but how do you figure out the limits of $r$ and $\theta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Before changing coordinates, factor $$e^{-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}e^{-z^2}$$ and separate the integral in $z$:
$$\iiint_R z e^{-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} dV = \int_0^1 ze^{-z^2} dz \iint_{{\Bbb R}^2} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dx\,dy .$$

> **Additional hint** We can integrate over ${\Bbb R}^2$ in polar coordinates simply by integrating over $$0 \leq r < \infty, \quad 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi.$$

Comment: +1 very nice! Without this writing the limit of integration in spheric coordinates would be unpleasant :)

Comment: @Travis the integration is easy. how did you just know he limits of r and theta though?

Comment: @Ant Thanks! It's not *so* different using cylindrical coordinates---the point of the first hint is (1) that, since the same coordinate $z$ occurs in both rectangular and cylindrical systems, we might as well isolate the coordinates that *are* transformed, and (2) the double integral on the r.h.s. is famous in its right, and isolating it emphasizes its evaluation.

Comment: @snowman The idea is to find a region in the $r\theta$-plane that covers each point in the $xy$-plane once, and this region does this. (Actually, the given ranges for $r, \theta$ cover the points on the closed positive $x$-axis twice, but this ray has area zero, so this redundancy does not affect the value of the integral.) Does that help?

Comment: @Travis Yes kinda. So it seems like of obvious that r is going to range over from 0 to infinity since it cant be negative. And putting theta from 0 to 2pi will definitely ensure no points are missed. Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: @snowman Yes, that's right. Have you used polar coordinates to set up a double integral over a disc of radius $R$ (centered at the origin)?

Comment: @Travis Yes I have. Why do you ask?

Comment: @snowman Then as you know, you just integrate over $[0, R] \times [0, 2 \pi]$ in $r\theta$-space. Heuristically, the plane is the limit of these discs as $R \to \infty$, giving the claimed subset $[0, \infty) \times [0, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

It's like in polar coordinates, where for the plane we have

$0<r<\infty,0<\theta<2\pi$

or

$-\infty<r<\infty,0<\theta<\pi$

Comment: We are in space, we should use spheric coordinates; so you need another angle $\psi$, but calculating where it varies it's unpleasant :) Better to just separate the integral and then use polar coordinates as @Travis answer shows :)

Comment: @Ant, that is just cylindrical coordinates as is pointed by OP.

Comment: ops! You're right, totally had a moment there :) +1 then ;)

Answer (score 0):

In cylinder coordinates with $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$ and Jacobian $r$
$$
\int_0^1 dz z e^{-z^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int _{-\infty}^\infty dy e^{-x^2-y^2}
$$
$$
=\int_0^1  dzz e^{-z^2}\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int _0^\infty r dr e^{-r^2}
$$
$$
=2\pi\int_0^1  dzz e^{-z^2} \int _0^\infty r dr e^{-r^2}
$$
$$
=\pi\int_0^1  dzz e^{-z^2} \int _0^\infty du e^{-u}
$$
$$
=\pi\int_0^1  dzz e^{-z^2}
$$
$$
=\frac12 \pi(1-\frac{1}{e})
$$